# Protecting IC in the event of SCL and SDA short circuit

Tags: i2c, tvs

I am looking for a circuitry to protect an IC in the event of a short circuit between SCL and SDA lines. I am considering using TVS on both SCL and SDA to GND. Would that be sufficient?

The power supply voltage is 5V. Max current of power supply is 200mA. The TVS I selected has the following characteristics:

Vrwm = 5.8V
Vbr = 6.45V
Clamp = 10.5V
App = 39A

Additional question: What about short circuit between SDA and GND and SCL and GND?

Answer (score 7):

A short between SCL and SDA is extremely unlikely to damage any chip with a compliant I2C interface. And if it does, a TVS on one or both lines won't change that.

I2C lines are pulled up with resistors and driven low with open-collector drivers. It is not uncommon for multiple drivers to simultaneously drive a line low; it is harmless. The only thing when the lines are shorted together, the pull-up resistors are paralleled; if they are marginally low valued, the resulting 1/2 resistance could overload a driver.

A short between SCL and SDA will make the I2C bus unusable until the short is removed, and that will likely make your circuit nonfunctional. But a TVS on one or both lines won't change that either.

The TVS will only activate if the protected line is connected to a voltage higher than its breakdown voltage. Since both SCL and SDA are limited to 5 V, the TVS will have no benefit or effect in case these lines are shorted together.

Comment: What about short circuit between SDA and GND and SCL and GND?

Comment: @user14665305 Again no damage. I2C lines are pulled up with resistors and the transmitters only pull the lines down to ground (open collector drivers). Shorting either line to ground will be no different (electrically) than them being driven low.

Comment: @thePhoton - I took the liberty of adding a paragraph to your answer, detailing how I2C lines work and the only possible danger of paralleling the pull-up resistors. Feel free to refine or remove it as you see fit.